# Convert to default value when value is null in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity

I have the following Entity Framework query and that query has a `DateTime` column called `by` and it is obtained from MySQL, but sometimes it is `NULL`, and I get an error

> The specified conversion is invalid.

I know it is resolved turning my model like

```
public by? { get; set; }
```

but I don't want to make it nullable, I would like to know if there is an attribute such as `[DefaultValue ()]`, which indicates that if a null is obtained, it will be converted to a default value, that is, a `DateTime.MinValue` is inserted so as not to convert the nullable datetime

```
var Context = new Context();

var docs = Context.Docs.AsNoTracking()
                  .Where(d => d.froms == "active")
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If it should not be null in the DB, then change the DB to not allow for nulls.  If it can be null there then you should have an entity that represents that.  Then you'd just code for it being null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no: Check available data annotations [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes). It is for core, but contains all EF 6 attributes as well.

It seems that EF makes a point of not allowing you to do that even with value conversions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

> A null value will never be passed to a value converter. This makes the implementation of conversions easier and allows them to be shared amongst nullable and non-nullable properties.

This makes sense, as you are effectively trying to bypass a configuration that you, yourself added to your project.

If it makes sense to have null values in your database, it should make sense for your code to have them too.

On any other (not null) case

> Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading from or writing to the database.

Comment: Just to add to that, EF Core allows specifying the database default value through the fluent API, which is a great new feature because it leads to a better database for other apps and users like DBAs. `.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")`

Comment: But that example of Fluent Api that you give me is for when a Migration or an insert is made? What I am looking for is to customize the answer on the column 'by' for example an `IFNULL (by, NOW ())`